# Android Broadcast with permission, protectionLevel dangerous

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast, android-permissions

I'm trying to send information over a intent (protectionlevel: dangerous) from application A to application B. I cannot use another protectionlevel since the two apps will use different certificates.

For this, I created two sample apps. But I am not able to send an intent with permission to another application.

Following failure from the adb-logcat:

> W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent {
>   act=ch.christofbuechi.android.mybroadcastRequest flg=0x10 (has extras)
>   } to ch.christofbuechi.httpexampleb/.UserCheckReceiverRequest requires
>   ch.christofbuechi.httpB_perm due to sender
>   ch.christofbuechi.httpexamplea

---

Sender has following properties:

```
<uses-permission android:name="ch.christofbuechi.httpB_perm"/>
```

In the Manifest

```
private void checkUserHA654321() {
    Log.d("BroadcastQueue", "send: checkUserHA654321");
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("ch.christofbuechi.android.mybroadcastRequest");
    intent.putExtra("User", "HA654321");
    sendBroadcast(intent, "ch.christofbuechi.httpB_perm");
}
```

As action inside activity

---

Receiver has following properties:

```
<permission android:name="ch.christofbuechi.httpB_perm" android:protectionLevel="dangerous"></permission>
```

and

```
<receiver android:name=".UserCheckReceiverRequest"
        android:permission="ch.christofbuechi.httpB_perm">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ch.christofbuechi.android.mybroadcastRequest" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

In the Manifest

---

Actually I dont know where my problem is. I already studied the other stackoverflow-posts regarding this topic. Maybe you can help me too ? Thx

Code can be fetched in complete from here:
(Made the samples as easy as possible)
https://github.com/ChristofBuechi/appswitch_sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to send information over a intent (protectionlevel: dangerous) from application A to application B.

That will only work if Application B is 100% guaranteed to be installed before Application A.

> Following failure from the adb-logcat:

That would suggest that Application B (the receiver) was installed after Application A (the sender).

`<uses-permission>` for a permission name that Android does not know about is ignored. You have to have the `<permission>` element first, to define the name. You might be tempted to have both apps define the same `<permission>`, but that will not work on Android 5.0+, because having more than one app (signed by different signing keys) define the same permission opens up some fairly nasty security problems.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But actually even if I install the receiver first, it is not working. It does not understand my definition of permission by the receiver. Btw I'm using Android 5.1.1 but we also tested on other devices

Comment: @ChristofBuechi: "It does not understand my definition of permission by the receiver" -- I do not know what "it" is or what "my definition of permission by the receiver" means.

Comment: sorry - I receive the same error as above. I am doing something wrong in defining the receiver, as I understand. Because, I already added the permission to my Receiver: UserCheckReceiverRequest. But still the same failure "Permission Denial"

Comment: you were right - the ordering of installing the applications is important. But beside that, I miss the <uses-permission> tag in the receiver application. This was my main problem. Even by defining the permission, the permission has to be "used" in the same application to be able to secure the receiver.